# Why a loop in batch file prints a message only at the last execution?

Tags: windows, batch-file

i want to make a batch file, This Batch file must look out, into a folder with the name "Draft" and for every sub-folder will be make a search for a .txt file "list.txt" and when finds this .txt file, Then will be execute a copy from the folder "Draft" to the folder "Ready". I have written a small script but i have some issues.

```
@echo off
:loop

  for /d %%i in ('dir "C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Draft" /ad /o:d /s /b') do ( 
  SET a=%%i
  echo %a%
  )

echo Folder is empty or does not exist
timeout /t 15
goto loop
```

The problem in this small part of the script is that, the variable "a" cannot save the name of the folder, if i change the `echo %a%` to `echo Hello World` then the script prints only one time the message and not as long as the loop runs. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are more bugs in the code but one problem is the missing of **delayed expansion**. Here is the fix:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:loop

  for /f %%i in ('dir "C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Draft" /ad /o:d /s /b') do ( 
  SET a=%%i
  echo !a!
  )

echo Folder is empty or does not exist
timeout /t 15
goto loop
```

You have to add `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the beginning of your script and replace `%a%` with `!a!`. You always to do this when changing a variable inside a for loop (and also in many other cases). For an explanation check http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

EDIT: replaced `for /d ...` with `for /f ...`

Comment: Thank you, your answer works 50% but it is a good advice, with the SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
works the loop and prints right the output of the "Hello World" but with the variable "a" still not working. It's printing only "ECHO is OFF" when i put %a% and when i put !a! then the code prints the elements of the command dir. Like \ad , \o:d etc.

Comment: @poprock: That's because you've miexed up `for /d` and `dir "C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Draft" /ad /o:d /s /b`. This is wrong. When iterating over directories you should either use `for /d ... in (PATH_TO_A_FOLDER)` or `for /f ... in ('dir something')`. Simply replace `for /d` with `for /f`. This should work. This link might be of use: http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

Comment: I’d prefer camel-case to improve readability: `EnableDelayedExpansion`. The interpreter is case-insensitive.

Comment: @Melebius: Sorry, this is not about your preferences or taste. This is not constructive.

Comment: @MichaelS Could you help me also with the search command `for /R %%t in (%%a\*.txt) do if "%%~nxt"=="files.txt" SET p=%%~dpnxt` Is this syntax right ?

Comment: As this is a different topic, please post it as a new question.